# Refreshing data without push notification

Tags: ios, swift

So I have build a chat,
Right one user1 sends text to user2.
user2 gets push notification, if the app is open then using the push notification code I'm re-downloading the data from server. 
So my question is, is there any way to reload data without push notification? like find when the content is available and download the data and reload the chat.
I'm pretty new ios programming so I don't know whats is exactly called or any ways to do it without getting a push and running a function.

Comment: Could be me but this question makes little sense. Could you clarify what you mean by redownloading the data? What data? From which service? What kind of text service?

Comment: You should try [Firebase](https://firebase.com/). Realtime data streaming to your app. (Disclosure: I work at Google on Firebase).

Comment: @TheBasicMind when you're chatting with someone, it downloads the data every time you recieve a message, so what i meant was, is there any other way then push notifications to find if new message/data is available

Answer (score 2):

There are only a couple of ways for a server to reach out to your app. Through push notifications (both silent and normal,) and using a socket. Sockets are more immediate but only work when your app is active in the foreground.

The only other option is for your app to poll the server. IE, for it to call a server outlet every few seconds and ask if there is any new information.

Comment: does silent and normal notification will work if user has disabled push notification for my app?

Comment: No, they won't. That's the whole point of disabling push notifications.

Comment: so i was wondering how facebook does it, i have disabled push notification but when I'm chatting on messenger app, it automatically reloads the data and shows the new message.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the app either uses push notifications, sockets or polling. If they aren't using notifications, then they are using sockets or polling.